# Change the default audio from AV Jack to card 3 (aplay -l)

Tags: audio

**What I want to do**

I attached **WM8960 Audio HAT** to **Raspberry Pi 4b 4GB** in order to attach a speaker.
I executed `aplay -l` and found that I wanted to change the default audio to **card3**.
[image]

**What I tried**

**1.** Tried to change from tool bar.

I tried to change from the tool bar, but there was no option for it.

[image]

**2.** Tried to change from **alsa.conf**

I tried to change **defaults.ctl.card 0** and **defaults.pcm.card 0** to **3**, but could not find a way to save.

**Therefore, I want to know how to save alsa.conf**.

```
sudo vi /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
```

[image]

If there are any other options to change the default audio, please help me.

**Link**

WM8960 Audio HAT https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/WM8960_Audio_HAT